# How to Get Callback message to my Backend side of my site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm developing a asp.net mvc site,
and I'm using a third party payment service that send me a callback
to my site after the payment approved.
according to them they send it server to server.

They send a Json to a specific url to my site- www.site.com/callback.

I Tried using a HttpListenrer but i receive nothing.

```
  public class PostListener
{
    Task task;
    public PostListener()
    {
        task = new Task(RunServer);
        task.Start();
    }

    private static async void RunServer()
    {
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("www.site.com/callback");
        listener.Start();

        new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                while (listener.IsListening)
                {
                    var ctx = listener.GetContext();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => ProcessRequest(ctx));
                }
            }
            ).Start();
    }

    private static void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext ctx)
    {

    }
}
```

But the listener.GetContext() doesn't return nothing after the payment approved,
Am I doing it all wrong and need to put the code inside the controller of the page or what?
Do I need to use a different method?

Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an method on your controller called: callback

```
[HttpGet]
[RouteUrl("callback")]
public ActionResult Callback(){
Return Ok();
}
```

Obviously, this has run in a live environment for them to reach you.

Comment: Thanks. But How can i get the json data in this way?

Comment: Add a parameter. Or if it's a POST you can take it from the form collection

Comment: they send me POST message, how can i get the json from the form collection?

Comment: Who are your payment provider? If it's stripe use something like: 

[HttpPost]
        [Route("StripeWebHook")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Stripe()
        {
            try
            {
                var requestContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: I'm using mvc controller not web api, so i don't have Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync, is there another way? thanks.

Comment: Thanks!!!.It finally worked after i did what you said with formcollection. but at the attribute i did HttpPost.

Answer (score 0):

The callback url is used to redirect back to your site when payment process is done. This is done by your payment gateway by their selves.

They send some information about the transaction, and you can get format of that information from their helping tutorial and declare an action which will accept same parameters. Now whenever your action is called, you will receive those parameters. I think there is no need to call listener.

```
public ActionResult Invoices(string JSonString)
{
    //Add System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace on top of the page
    MyModel myModelObject = 
               new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyModel>(JSonString);
    //Use myModelObject, save to db, display message
    return View();
}
```

You should create MyModel class with properties you are expected to receive in JSON data.

Comment: I suppose to get it in the form of json, how does the action supposed to look? can you give me an example please?